# VB how can i make button refresh back to original text?

Tags: vb.net, button, combobox, textbox

I have a simple translating program i working on in vb 2010.

I have a combobox and a textbox and a button.

What i have so far is when you select the option in the combobox the textbox and button will appear. then when you type something it replaces each letter with something new, in the same textbox.

what i cant figure out is how to make it so where if i click the button again it translates the replaced letters back to the original ones.

how would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copying your text to a string before you replace it, then replace the text in the textbox with the contents of your string when you click your 2nd button something like this.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim backingString As String
    Dim bConverted As Boolean

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not bConverted Then
            backingString = TextBox1.Text
            bConverted = True
            If TextBox1.Text.Contains("A") Then
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("A", "/-\")
            End If
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = backingString
            backingString = ""
            bConverted = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And how would i copy the text to a string? Im new to vb

Comment: @ryan I just added a code example also which event are you using to capture your key presses

Comment: Thanks for your help but i honestly still don't under stand that. I put that in but it changed all my characters i have implemented in my code. 

the method i uses for replacing letters was this


If TextBox1.Text.Contains("A") Then
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("A", "/-\")
        End If

Comment: @ryan I just used something to generate random jibberish, I wasn't expecting you to use it. Which Textbox event are you using to change your code that will have a bearing on what I suggest.

Comment: haha sorry i am a rookie at this. I dont think i have a textbox event. I just used the above method in my button code for every letter of the alphabet. That makes it so when i type in the textbox and click the button text was replaced. but i cant get it to go back to original. 

Please dont mind at how stupid i may sound. I am trying to learn.

Comment: @ryan that helps give me a minute

Comment: @ryan That should do what you want. I am using a boolean variable to allow your one button to do 2 functions

Comment: okay i will try thanks alot man. So if i understand correctly a button can only perform one action unless you use a boolean action? Yes that is working so far like a charm thanks man.

Comment: one little problem, if i type something new over the translated text the button still goes back to old text. i only want the button to go back to old text if the translation is still there. but if i type something new after clicking button i want it to translate the new text

Comment: @ryan Try resetting the Boolean variable in your keydown event

Comment: so i must first create a keydown event? Should i create it for the button or for the textboxt or both?

Comment: I added an answer to your other question. You need to add it to the Textbox that way when you press a key it will reset the boolean variable and allow you to re encrypt your text.

Comment: Okay to the textbox, that makes sense. Let me go check my other question to see whats there. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

When the user types something in, can what they typed be captured in a "hidden" textbox while your visible textbox is what is being displayed (which I assume is the translation). Then, once the user clicks the button to display what they posted you could hide the translated textbox and show the hidden one with the original text. It would look something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    TextBox1.Visible = False    
    TextBox2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Of course, clicking it again would not reverse it, so I would suggest a two button strategy (1 hidden, 1 visible). Then when the user clicks the button to show what they typed, the hidden button would appear, so it would be like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    TextBox1.Visible = False    
    TextBox2.Visible = True
    Button1.Visible = False
    Button2.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click()
    TextBox1.Visible = True    
    TextBox2.Visible = False
    Button1.Visible = True
    Button2.Visible = False 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Public Class Form1

This is how I would do it and I think this is the most simple way.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Static buttonHits As Integer

        buttonHits += 1

        If IsOdd(buttonHits) = True Then
            Button1.Text = "New"
        Else
            Button1.Text = "Original"
        End If

    End Sub

    Function IsOdd(ByVal iNum As Integer) As Boolean
        IsOdd = ((iNum \ 2) * 2 <> iNum)

    End Function
End Class
```