# I have a "bug/glitch" in my vb program need assistance

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox

I have a program that replaces every letter of the alphabet with something new inside the same textbox by clicking a button then buy clicking the button it translates it back to original text.

However when i run this program, yes it does work as needed but not 100%

Because after i click the button to translate, (yes it shows translated)
If delete the translated text and type something new, it goes back to the old text.

(this does not happen if i click the button again, it shows the orignal text. But if i type something new it will translate it.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: i want the button to go back to old text only if soemthign new wasent typed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a continuation of your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238333/vb-how-can-i-make-button-refresh-back-to-original-text). You will need to reset your `Boolean` variable when you type in your `TextBox`  i.e.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    bConverted = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. Although i am not very good at explaning things so maybe i said something wrong.

Comment: @ryan How did you add the event handler? It should reset bConverted and allow the button to encrypt again. Try putting a Break Point on bConveted = False to make sure you are hitting it.

Comment: Okay i got it to work, instead of copying and pasting i typed from memory and missed a letter. I have a question, Is there any good online sites to go to a learn this for free? I am so new to this that i find it hard to know everything. Any recommendations on where to start?

Comment: I'm so far in the river that my hat is almost floating. Maybe i shouldnt have jumped into this project like this. But in a way i guess it will help me learn from it.

Comment: @ryan You could  try [Programmers Paridise](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/VB-NET-SCHOOL) or this site http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/vbNET.html. The Microsoft [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388568) documention is also good

Comment: thanks a lot again. You have helped me so much. Your are very hq. And from your profile i see you have never asked a question? Which is even more amazing that you help so many others. Cheers to you and much respect.

Comment: @ryan The way you learn is to stretch yourself, there are resources out there to help you. Programming is a different way of thinking and you will eventually get the hang of it.

Comment: yeah your right, hopefully one day i will be here as you are, helping other people. Okay well i'm off to the first leeson